# batch file ren command Self destruct

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, batch-rename

sorry for the noob question, but i'm a beginner.
I have a .bat that turns all of the folders containment's to a .jpeg using a wiled card because the containment's are empty extensions

```
@echo off

ren * *.jpeg
```

the thing is to make it run i put the bat in the folder that i want the files to change but it changes it self as well.
is there a way to make the .bat Self destruct (delete it self) when its done, so i can just have a master .bat and copy it to where i need it.

thanks for the help :)

Comment: Add  DEL "%~f0" at the end, to delete your .bat file.

Answer (score 2):

Create .BAT file on your desktop

### [RenameAllFilesInFolder.BAT]

```
ren %1\* *.jpeg
```

When you need to rename all files in some folder then simply drag this folder onto this .BAT file.

Answer (score 0):

- So, 2 options to you....

  ---

> ## The 1st Option:
>
> ---

1) There is no necessity, to copy the bat and paste it for later and perform it with self deletion.

2) No need copy this bat to some target folder anywhere the .jpeg are, just click it!

```bat
<!-- :
@echo off && cls && mode 050,02 && title <nul && title ...\%~nx0
for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%cScript.exe "%~dpnx0?.wsf"
')do if "%%i"=="Cancelled" (cd.&echo/Cancelled by %Username%^!!!
) else for %%J in (*)do if /i "%%~xJ"=="" ren "%%~fJ" "%%~nJ.jpeg"
exit /b || goto :EOF
# -->
<job><script language="vbscript">
Option Explicit
Function SelectFolder( myStartFolder )
Dim objFolder, objItem, objShell
    On Error Resume Next
    SelectFolder = vbNull
    Set objShell  = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Select Folder", 0, myStartFolder )
    If IsObject( objfolder ) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objshell  = Nothing
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
Dim strPath
strPath = SelectFolder( "" )
If strPath = vbNull Then
    WScript.Echo "Cancelled"
Else
    WScript.Echo strPath
```

---

- Just save as **`some_file.cmd`** and run/click it:

  ---

[image]

---

---

> ## The 2nd Option:
>
> ---

- As request, the **`file.bat`** self deleter!

  ---

1) Copy/paste where you need to use it, and say gooday before click them!

2) The bat renames all files with no extension in name, then will be abducted by itself to an unknown location.

```bat
@echo off && mode 050,002 && title <nul && title ...\\%~nx0
for %%J in (*)do if /i "%%~xJ"=="" ren "%%~fJ" "%%~nJ.jpeg"
echo=exit|cmd/k "2>nul >nul del /q /f "%~dpnx0"" && exit /b
```

---

[image]

---

<sub>Sorry my limited **English**</sub>